# .mdf file is not created on ASP.Net MVC 4 app after adding <connectionStrings> tag on Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying the [ASP.Net MVC 4 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model). When I have added the following code and build the application I was expecting Movies.mdf file will be created under **App_Data** folder on the **Solution Explorer**. However, nothing has been created in that directory. Any idea why?

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" 
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-2012213181139;Integrated Security=true" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>    
  <add name="MovieDBContext" 
   connectionString="Data Source= (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
 </connectionStrings>
```

Using:
.NET Framework 4
VS 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved. The problem was the location of the project. I was working with the files from a shared drive which apparently did not create the database in the **App_Data** folder. Connectionstring code is absolutely fine as it is shown in the tutorial and no changes are required.

Answer (score 2):

Having a full instance of MS SQL 2012 on my machine, not SqlExpress, I had this problem. I found that by letting the application continue (instead of halting it in visual studio when VS catches the exception) I got a helpful message in the browser:

> Directory lookup for the file "c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\App_Data\aspnet-MvcApplication1-20140225162244.mdf"
>   failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.). CREATE
>   DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check
>   related errors.

which tells that the problem is that the sql service doesn't have write permissions to my application directory.

Giving it permissions was slightly tricky because the username needed didn't come up (in Windows 8 Pro) in the Explorer GUI for Security. The username  for a Default Instance of Sql Server is `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` (for an instance it's `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$InstanceName`) and I had to type it in by hand, and then give it write permissions. I did this just on the App_data directory.

Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The database will not be created before you actually add the first record to one of your tables.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when Visual studio and MSSQL are running under different authorities. For this reason, your application doesn't get to have a write permission for creating the `.mdf` database file.

**SOLUTION**

1. Open `SQL Server Configuration Manager`
2. Select `SQL Server Services`
3. See the `Log On As` tab

   *the value would be something like `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE` ( it depends )*

---

Once you get the user name,

1. then go to the target folder. ( If default, `App_Data` in your project directory )
2. right click -> property windows -> security tab
3. click edit -> check the user or group name

   *You shall not see there's no `Network Service` on the user or group name list*

All you have to do is to add the user name and give the write permission for that user or group.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case of AttachDBFilename...  I have this for my project and it works fine.

```
... connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Movies.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Also verify your model is correct.  If your model does not initiate this connection then it will not create the database.

Comment: Only difference  I can see is Movies instead of \Movies. When you say model is correct, what exactly could be problem on Movie.cs file? I can see few codes are in black text which in the tutorial is in green. ANy idea why that could be?

Comment: Also note the B is capital in the AttachDBFilename  If you replace your connection string line with mine via copy and paste does it work?  Visual Studio should do context highlighting automatically.  If it is not picking up the words it could be a case issue or missing punctuation.  Your model should be just as it is in the example.  If you copy and pasted it should pick up the context.

Comment: unfortunately no luck. I copied Movie.cs file content exactly from the tutorial.No punctuation is missing but the variables for example are in black text instead of green. Still no Movies.mdf is created. I tried copy pasting your text part too. Still no luck. Would I be missing something else?I tried to access localdb through Server Management Studio, couldn't access that either.

Comment: @shaz I am assuming you installed mvc4 - http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 and installed and sql server compact or sql express.  These come standard with visual studio 2012.  I use 2012 so I haven't done this in awhile.

Comment: @shaz if you notice the example uses .sdf which is the sql server compact.  SQL Express would produce the .mdf file.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by modifying the connectionstring like below

```
 <add name="MovieDBContext"
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Movies;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I did install Microsoft SQl Server Compact 4.0 from nuget.. but I am not sure whether it is really require to install it or not.

Answer (score 0):

In this `MVC` tutorial, just add "`Initial Catalog=Movies`;" (without quote) to the `connection string` and it'll work well.

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Movies;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```